# Is there any way to exit the application when home button is pressed on Android?

Tags: android

I want to kill the app when user presses the home button. Is there any way to do this on Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented something similar by overriding `Activity.onUserLeaveHint()`. This method gets called once home key is pressed but I think there where some caveats I can't remember right now. Namely it got called on situations I didn't want my application to finish and had to put flags to prevent unwanted exits.

Comment: Sorry I did'nt see your answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

when pressed Home, your app will hiden and will invoke `onStop` method, so you can invoke `finish` in the `onStop` method.

**But if another application be front of your app, also your app will hide, so can not identify Home pressed or another application rightly, so suggestion use follow:**

```
    static final String SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_KEY = "reason";

    static final String SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_GLOBAL_ACTIONS = "globalactions";

    static final String SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_RECENT_APPS = "recentapps";

    static final String SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_HOME_KEY = "homekey";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS)) {   
            String reason = intent.getStringExtra(SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_KEY); 
            if (reason != null) {
                Lg.i("receive action:" + action + ",reason:" + reason);
                if (mListener != null) {
                    if (reason.equals(SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_HOME_KEY)) {
                        mListener.onHomePressed();
                    } else if (reason.equals(SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_RECENT_APPS)) {
                        mListener.onHomeLongPressed();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

here is a complement code [HomeWatcher](http://idiottiger.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/HomeWatcher.java_.txt)

Answer (score 0):

called finish() on your Activity.

Ref:

[Activity's finish() method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29)

Comment: This method just finishes the activity. However I want to finish the application.

Comment: if pressing home is taking you back on home screen then its automatically finishing the application too, unless you are not running a service besides your activity with in the same application

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
@Override
public void onUserLeaveHint() {
    finish();
}
```

You will find more details here :

http://tech.chitgoks.com/2011/09/05/how-to-override-back-home-button-in-an-android-app/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't write your own home app - do not provide any special action for home or back buttons. Read [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon) for good explanation why you don't need this

Answer (score -2):

JoxTraex answer is right but maybe specify that you can capture home button to be able to execute finish on the activity you want:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
    //Handle the back button
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) { 
           finish();
        }
    }
```

Comments are right, I just tried with **KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK** sorry!
Then I would try overwriting onStart() and onStop() functions for each activity to know when there is no more activities opened on my app.

Comment: KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME is never forwarded to applications but handled by system.

Comment: Wrong : you can't handle home button like this. It's forbidden.

Comment: You are not able to listen to the home keypress. This is forbidden.